# Oracle SQL Iterate through each item

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple requirement that aims to achieve the following:

```
 Resulting_column_1     Resulting_column_2
 Apple                  Orange
 Apple                  Banana
 Apple                  Cherry
 Orange                 Apple
 Orange                 Banana
 Orange                 Cherry
 Banana                 Apple
 Banana                 Orange
 Banana                 Cherry
 Cherry                 Apple
 Cherry                 Banana
 Cherry                 Orange
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "FRUITS" 
(   "FRUIT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100)
) ;

insert into fruits (fruit_name) values ('Apple')
insert into fruits (fruit_name) values ('Banana')
insert into fruits (fruit_name) values ('Cherry')
insert into fruits (fruit_name) values ('Orange')
```

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to itself where the names are **not** equal to each other:

```
select f1.fruit_name f1, f2.fruit_name f2
from   fruits f1
join   fruits f2
on     f1.fruit_name <> f2.fruit_name;

F1        F2        
Apple     Banana    
Apple     Cherry    
Apple     Orange    
Banana    Apple     
Banana    Cherry    
Banana    Orange    
Cherry    Apple     
Cherry    Banana    
Cherry    Orange    
Orange    Apple     
Orange    Banana    
Orange    Cherry
```

Comment: To expand on Chris solution if your looking for only unique combinations  select f1.fruit_name f1, f2.fruit_name f2 from fruits f1 join fruits f2 on f1.fruit_name < f2.fruit_name;